# Need to convert array to comma separated and ; separated multi dimension array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach

Below is a sample array which has a multidimensional array. I need to separate the values as comma separated and semicolon separated as the expected output

```json
"grpdet": [
  {
    "id": 36,
    "name": "GROUP TOP A",
    "stud": [
      {
        "id": 114,
        "name": "test_stu_1"
      },
      {
        "id": 115,
        "name": "test_stu_2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "name": "GROUP TOP B",
    "stud": [
      {
        "id": 116,
        "name": "test_stu_3"
      },
      {
        "id": 117,
        "name": "test_stu_4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 38,
    "name": "GROUP TOP C",
    "stud": [
      {
        "id": 118,
        "name": "test_stu_5"
      },
      {
        "id": 119,
        "name": "test_stu_6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 39,
    "name": "GROUP TOP D",
    "stud": [
      {
        "id": 120,
        "name": "test_stu_7"
      },
      {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "test_stu_8"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
GROUP TOP A,test_stu_1,test_stu_2;GROUP TOP B,test_stu_3,test_stu_4;GROUP TOP C,test_stu_4,test_stu_5;
```

I have tried using `forEach` but `;` and `,` appear in the same line.

Comment: "i have tried using for each" -- please share your attempt as a [mcve]. We can't help with code you haven't shown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a combined use of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) operations, and taking advantage of the fact that the default `toString()` result of an array is already a comma-separated string:

```
const result = data.map((g) => [g.name, g.stud.map((s) => s.name)]).join(';');
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 36,
  "name": "GROUP TOP A",
  "stud": [{
    "id": 114,
    "name": "test_stu_1"
  }, {
    "id": 115,
    "name": "test_stu_2"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 37,
  "name": "GROUP TOP B",
  "stud": [{
    "id": 116,
    "name": "test_stu_3"
  }, {
    "id": 117,
    "name": "test_stu_4"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 38,
  "name": "GROUP TOP C",
  "stud": [{
    "id": 118,
    "name": "test_stu_5"
  }, {
    "id": 119,
    "name": "test_stu_6"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 39,
  "name": "GROUP TOP D",
  "stud": [{
    "id": 120,
    "name": "test_stu_7"
  }, {
    "id": 121,
    "name": "test_stu_8"
  }]
}];

const result = data.map((g) => [g.name, g.stud.map((s) => s.name)]).join(';');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The required output can be achieved using forEach.

```js
var grpdet = [{ id: 36, name: 'GROUP TOP A', stud: [{ id: 114, name: 'test_stu_1', }, { id: 115, name: 'test_stu_2', },], }, { id: 37, name: 'GROUP TOP B', stud: [{ id: 116, name: 'test_stu_3', }, { id: 117, name: 'test_stu_4', },], }, { id: 38, name: 'GROUP TOP C', stud: [{ id: 118, name: 'test_stu_5', }, { id: 119, name: 'test_stu_6', },], }, { id: 39, name: 'GROUP TOP D', stud: [{ id: 120, name: 'test_stu_7', }, { id: 121, name: 'test_stu_8', },], },];

var result = '';

grpdet.forEach((elem, index) => {
  result += elem.name;
  elem.stud.forEach((s, i) => {
    result += ',' + s.name;
  });
  result += ';';
});
console.log(result);
```